# If you choose 4 of these lamps at random, what is the probability that none need to be replaced during the first $150$ hours of use?

Tags: probability

> The lifetime, in hours, of each lamp produced by a certain company, is a random variable with density function given by
>   $$f(t)=\begin{cases}100/t^2,& t>100\\
> 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
>   If you choose $4$ of these lamps random, what is the probability that,
>   a) none need to be replaced during the first $150$ hours of use?
>   b) at least $2$ have to be replaced during the first $160$ hours of use?

I made the integral of the function and I obtain $P(T>150)=2/3$, but next I don't know what to do, can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) At the moment, you have the chance $p$ that a bulb will last more than 150 hours. In other words, the chance that it will not be replace in 150 hours is $p = 2/3$.

But this is for one particular lamp. You have four, and assuming the lifetimes are independent, you have four independent trials with probability $p$ of success (not being replaced in 150). This is a binomial distribution.

Another way to put it is that you need the lamp is not replaced four times, which is
$$\binom{4}{4}\left(\frac23\right)^4\left(\frac13\right)^0$$

b) This follows a similar logic to a)

Comment: In the b) I find $p=5/8$, but I think I have to rest 1, so $p=1-5/8 = 3/8$, but I not sure...

Comment: "have to rest 1"? You have $5/8$. This is the chance that a lamp lives longer than 160 hours. $1-5/8 = 3/8$ is the chance that a lamp lives less than 160 (needs to be replaced). If you call "need to be replaced" a success, then you have 4 independent trials probability $3/8$ of being replaced. What is this distribution and what is the final result?

Comment: Ok, if you want to call $3/8$ $p$, and if you have four independent lamp lifetimes, then the number of lamps that need replacement before 160 hours follows what distribution?

Comment: sorry for my english I want so say substrabt 1,  $p=1−5/8=3/8$, and I obtain $1-$$\binom{4}{0}\left(\frac38\right)^0\left(\frac58\right)^0$$- $$\binom{4}{1}\left(\frac38\right)^1\left(\frac58\right)^1$$ =0.481201

Comment: thanks, I have not much time in this site

Comment: You are welcome. Consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to my answer. Thanks, and good luck!